# SQL 2000 Row numbering with GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server-2000

This is my Table

```
################################
# id_formfield # ID # int_Sort #
################################
#      1       # 1  #     2    #
#      2       # 1  #     3    #
#      3       # 1  #     4    #
#      4       # 1  #     4    #
#      5       # 1  #     4    #
#      6       # 2  #     1    #
#      7       # 2  #     3    #
#      8       # 2  #     3    #
#      9       # 2  #     4    #
```

As you can see my int_sort column is messed up somehow with equal numbers and I wanna to make it sequence with row number and reset row number when ID changes. 
this should be result:

```
############################################
# id_formfield # ID # int_Sort # rownumber #
############################################
#      1       # 1  #     2    #     1     #
#      2       # 1  #     3    #     2     #
#      3       # 1  #     4    #     3     #
#      4       # 1  #     4    #     4     #
#      5       # 1  #     4    #     5     #
#      6       # 2  #     1    #     1     #
#      7       # 2  #     3    #     2     #
#      8       # 2  #     3    #     3     #
#      9       # 2  #     4    #     4     #
```

Edit : id_formfield is my primary key and order by int_sort ascending

Comment: Do you have a primary key in this table?

Comment: yes I do, also another columns that didn't mention

Comment: Please, specify the field (or combination of fields) that: 1) uniquely identifies the record 2) defines the ordering of the rows. Without these 2 points the result will be unpredictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following script should get you started. In a nutshell, the script

- creates a temp table, adding an `IDENTITY` column to serve as rownumber
- inserts your original data into the temp table
- uses `MIN(Rownumber)` for each `ID` to get an offset.
- `JOIN` the temp table with the calculated offsets to restart the count for each group.

**SQL Statement**

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (Rownumber INTEGER IDENTITY(1, 1), ID INTEGER)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TempTable OFF

INSERT INTO #TempTable
SELECT      *
FROM        YourOriginalTable
ORDER BY    ID, int_Sort

SELECT    t.ID, t.Rownumber, t.Rownumber - o.Offset
FROM      #TempTable t
          INNER JOIN (
            SELECT    ID, MIN(Rownumber) - 1 AS Offset
            FROM      #TempTable
            GROUP BY  ID
          ) o ON o.ID = t.ID            


DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

**Test script**

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE (ID VARCHAR(1))
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (Rownumber INTEGER IDENTITY(1, 1), ID INTEGER)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TempTable OFF
INSERT INTO @YourTable (ID) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @YourTable (ID) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @YourTable (ID) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @YourTable (ID) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @YourTable (ID) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @YourTable (ID) VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO @YourTable (ID) VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO @YourTable (ID) VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO @YourTable (ID) VALUES (2)

INSERT INTO #TempTable
SELECT      *
FROM        @YourTable
ORDER BY    ID

SELECT    t.ID, t.Rownumber, t.Rownumber - o.Offset
FROM      #TempTable t
          INNER JOIN (
            SELECT    ID, MIN(Rownumber) - 1 AS Offset
            FROM      #TempTable
            GROUP BY  ID
          ) o ON o.ID = t.ID            


DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a primary key in your table that is called `PK` and that you want to update the column `int_sort`.

```
select cast(PK as int) as PK,
       ID,
       identity(int, 1, 1) as rownumber
into #T
from YourTable
order by ID, int_sort

update YourTable
set int_sort = T.rownumber - T2.rownumber + 1 
from #T as T
  inner join (
               select ID, min(rownumber) as rownumber
               from #T
               group by ID
             ) as T2
    on T.ID = T2.ID
where T.PK = YourTable.PK


drop table #T
```

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed that your Primary Key column is named `idpk`. You can obtain the desired row numbers using the following query:

```sql
SELECT ts.id, ts.int_sort,
  (SELECT count(*) FROM tosort
    WHERE id = ts.id AND int_sort <= ts.int_sort
      AND idpk <= ts.idpk) AS row_number
  FROM tosort AS ts
 ORDER BY ts.id, ts.int_sort, ts.idpk;
```

I have created a sample case on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/47b2f/5), though only 2008 R2 is available there.
I hope this will work on SQL Server 2000.